# Help to run a formula where I can get the total of the most units sold in "any given" 30 day cycle

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 columns.

Column 1 are randomised dates over a period of time.
Column 2 are quantities sold to customers of stock wrt respective dates.
Column 2 could have more than 1 entry if sold to multiple customers.

Ex:
15th Jan 2022 , Sold units 1
15th Jan 2022 , Sold units 2
17th Jan 2022,  Sold units 1
18th Jan 2022,  Sold units 1
18th Jan 2022,  Sold units 1
and so on with randomised data till Dec 2022.

How do I run a formula where I can get the  total of the most units sold in "any given" 30 day cycle?

Let's assume from 15th June till 30th June I sold a total of 10 units.
Then from 1st July till 12th July I sold 14 units.
Now in a 30 day cycle, that answer would be 26.

Hope you can help because I've looked around a lot for the answer to this query.

Comment: Please provide scripts to generate testdata.

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), especially #5 and #3.

Comment: *How do I run a formula where I can get the total of the most units sold in "any given" 30 day cycle.* ```SUM(quantity) OVER (ORDER BY timestamp RANGE BETWEEN 30 DAY PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)```